# How to set up JRebel in a Tomcat environment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jrebel

I'm having a hard time getting JRebel to work in my current development environment.

I have multi module maven projects. Currently, the Tomcat instance is controlled via service (tomcat monitor) and the deployed web apps are configured with a XML located at **${catalina.home}/conf/Catalina/localhost** where the docBase attribute points **${absolute maven project path}/target/app** (and the attribute reloadable is true). So every time I do a maven build I only have to manually restart tomcat if there any classes changed. If the modifications occurred in the static resources (JSP, HTML, JS, 
etc..) a page refresh will do it.

On my first attempt, I configured the web apps to run on a tomcat server running inside Eclipse. The maven plugin provided was also configured with success: all my sub-modules inherited the plugin configuration and I can saw in the tomcat startup the output messages from JRebel indicating the absolute project paths that were been listen. The only problem is that Eclipse WTP / Tomcat plugins don't go weel with War overlay feature in eclipse. After starting the server, only the resources present in the last web app (the module that have other War as dependencies) were deployed.

So, I returned to my original configuration development and introduced JRebel to it. I passed the JRebel java options to the Tomcat Vm, all maven modules had the rebel.xml (listening to the correct resource folders), but nothing happens. I can't see the usual JRebel messages and I experimented changing a JSP in the source folder and do a page refresh but the file ins't automatically redeployed (in this case a simple copy from the source folder the the ${maven.projec}/target/app will do the trick).

My two questions are:

1. It's possible to over come that eclipse WTP issue?
2. What is a funcional development environment involving maven eclipse and a external tomcat?

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

UPDATE 1

So, I got it. Kind of...I'm still struggling with the war modules overlaying. I have a main web app module that depends on several webapps modules. Because the rebel.xml it's generated dynamically via jrebel maven plugin when the main webapp build occurs, only the it's jrebel.xml prevail. All the other are squashed. The rebel.xml for the jars modules are at the right places (inside the jar file).

I can get it work if I create a custom rebel.xml for the main webapp that points to all the absolute directories containing the source files (static files such as JSP, HTML, JS, CSS, images, etc.) of the depending web apps. But this is worthless for my team development environments. I'm using maven properties but we've have two different maven multi-module hierarchy that don't know about each other and I can't use a root pom to connect them. So these kind of properties will not be enough to guarantee that the absolute paths generated on each developer machine in the rebel.xml are correct.

For now, I'm trying to tackle using some kind of maven plugin to do the rebel.xml merge. For the record without success yet.

This is becoming another issue a bit different of the original question :) Maybe I should through another question.

---

UPDATE 2

I got it working!..finally.
I used the [XSLT Generator Maven Plugin](http://xsltmp.sourceforge.net/examples/single.html) to help me merge the various rebel.xml files. Also had to use the fabulous [Maven Copy Plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Maven-copy-plugin) because the xslt transformation occurred after the final war packaging and I had to add the resulting rebel.xml to that WAR.

If someone needs the configuration files details down't hesitate asking.

Hope's this helps someone out there.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328604/tomcat-and-eclipse-zero-turnaround-deployment

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My actual development set up without JRebel is really close to the one described by philwb. I'm trying to move to JRebel because we've a multi module project with several wars overlays and local jars dependencies during the build. It's almost impossible to set up a working Eclipse environment to dealt with this situation without some kind of "help".

Comment: Hello Pedro.
Add you update as answer, and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!..finally. I used the XSLT Generator Maven Plugin to help me merge the various rebel.xml files. Also had to use the fabulous Maven Copy Plugin because the xslt transformation occurred after the final war packaging and I had to add the resulting rebel.xml to that WAR.