# Turnaround Time in Spring JBoss Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, jboss, thymeleaf, spring-tool-suite

I am currently writing a site in Spring, Thymeleaf, JBoss and I am using Spring Tool Suite.  The turnaround time is horrible.  I have to recompile and package the app, every time I make a change and then push it out to the server.  How to make my turnaround time quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try JRebel. You can get it free if you spread some social media love for them.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: Indeed, JRebel can map the running app to the active workspace so that the changes will be monitored and JRebel is able to propagate 'em without having to rebuild and redeploy the app. It has very good support for Spring. Thymeleaf is also supported. Just download the plugin from Eclipse Marketplace - it is easy to set up.

Comment: It works works like a champ and was easy to set up.  I tried it with a change to my Spring controller and it worked without any action from me.  I am going to test the bounds later, but JRebel meets my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a tool which supports **continuous integration**, and which supports working on an **exploded war file**.

For example, *sbt* supports that mode. It integrates *jetty*, and the webapp is restarted, if a source file changes (resources like .html, .css and .jsp do not restart the container).

As for details look here: [Eclipse + Tomcat - Serve webapp directly from workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496135/2390083). This question shows other possibilities as well.

If you use EJB features like session beans, you can split your project. If the EJB and pressentation is kept separate, the turn around times for redeploying EJB ears are acceptable.